# Interpolating lat/lon columns in PySpark to get equally spaced points in a trajectory

Tags: pyspark, interpolation, shapely

I have a PySpark dataframe containing Lat/Lon points for different trajectories identified by a column "trajectories_id". Each trajectory is made by a different number of points.
A very simple example is the following. Note that in my case I could have more complex (non straight) lines.

| trajectory_id | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | 5 |
| 1 | 45 | 6 |
| 1 | 45 | 9 |
| 2 | 46 | 1 |
| 2 | 46 | 5 |

What I want to do is to interpolate each trajectory_id to get a user-defined number of equally spaced points. Note that the first and last points are fixed. In the example above, if the number of points per line is set to be 5, the result would be:

| trajectory_id | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | 5 |
| 1 | 45 | 6 |
| 1 | 45 | 7 |
| 1 | 45 | 8 |
| 1 | 45 | 9 |
| 2 | 46 | 1 |
| 2 | 46 | 2 |
| 2 | 46 | 3 |
| 2 | 46 | 4 |
| 2 | 46 | 5 |

Using Pandas, one way to achieve this could be to use the shapely library, converting each line in a linestring and then using numpy’s `linspace` and shapely’s `interpolate`. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to achieve the same result in PySpark

```
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 45,5], [1, 45,6], [1, 45,9],[2, 46,1], [2, 46,5]], columns=['trajectory_id', 'latitude','longitude'])
df['point']=df[["longitude", "latitude"]].apply(Point, axis=1)
geo_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['trajectory_id', 'latitude','longitude'])
for i in range(1,df['trajectory_id'].max()+1):
    df_line = LineString(df['point'][df['trajectory_id']==i].reset_index(drop=True))
    distances = np.linspace(0, df_line.length, 5)
    df_points = gpd.GeoDataFrame([df_line.interpolate(distance) for distance in distances],columns=['geometry'])
    df_points['longitude'] = df_points.geometry.x
    df_points['latitude'] = df_points.geometry.y
    df_points['trajectory_id'] = i
    geo_df=geo_df.append(df_points)
del geo_df['geometry']
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a UDF to generate a range of integers, I can generate your expected data. It will work with ranges of **both lat and lon** (your sample only show a range of lon)

```py
def nums(f, t):
    return list(range(f, t + 1))

(df
    .groupBy('trajectory_id') # Group by `trajectory_id` to get min max lat and lon
    .agg(
        F.min('lat').alias('min_lat'),
        F.max('lat').alias('max_lat'),
        F.min('lon').alias('min_lon'),
        F.max('lon').alias('max_lon'),
    )
    .withColumn('lat_arr', F.udf(nums, T.ArrayType(T.IntegerType()))('min_lat', 'max_lat')) # using UDF to generate list of lat values based on min max lat
    .withColumn('lon_arr', F.udf(nums, T.ArrayType(T.IntegerType()))('min_lon', 'max_lon')) # using UDF to generate list of lon values based on min max lon
    .withColumn('lat', F.explode('lat_arr')) # break down lat values to multiple rows
    .withColumn('lon', F.explode('lon_arr')) # break down lon values to multiple rows
    .drop('min_lat', 'max_lat', 'min_lon', 'max_lon', 'lat_arr', 'lon_arr') # drop temporary columns
    .show()
)

# +-------------+---+---+
# |trajectory_id|lat|lon|
# +-------------+---+---+
# |            1| 45|  5|
# |            1| 45|  6|
# |            1| 45|  7|
# |            1| 45|  8|
# |            1| 45|  9|
# |            2| 46|  1|
# |            2| 46|  2|
# |            2| 46|  3|
# |            2| 46|  4|
# |            2| 46|  5|
# +-------------+---+---+
```